# How to find index of 2 lists and merge them according to their index into one?

Tags: python

I have 2 lists as below:

```
list1 = ["jr", "sr", "manager"]
list2 = ["james", "william", "tim"]
```

I would like to combine the first element of list1 and then list2 and the pattern goes on.

Expected Output:

```
list3 = ["jr", "James", "sr", "william", "manager", "tim"]
```

I have tried the below:

```
list3 = []
list3.extend(name[0::])
list3.extend(rank[0::1])
print(list3)
```

but it fails to give me the expected output. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in `zip` method to do what you want

```
men = list(zip(list1, list2))
```

> `[('jr', 'james'), ('sr', 'william'), ('manager', 'tim')]`

```py
for rank, name in men:
    print(rank, name)

# jr james
# sr William
# manager tim
```

Answer (score 2):

If your `list`s are always same length just use `zip` and flatten result:

```
list1 = ["jr", "sr", "manager"]
list2 = ["james", "william", "tim"]
result = [item for sublist in zip(list1, list2) for item in sublist]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['jr', 'james', 'sr', 'william', 'manager', 'tim']
```

Comment: What if both lists aren't of the same length? For example:

list1 = ["manager"]
list2 = ["james", "william", "tim"]

Comment: @Natan it will cut longer list to length of shorter, so if `list1 = ["manager"]` and `list2 = ["james", "william", "tim"]` then output is `['manager', 'james']`

Answer (score 1):

Using `zip()` builtin method:

```
list1 = ["jr", "sr", "manager"]
list2 = ["james", "william", "tim"]

out = []
for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
    out.append(a)
    out.append(b)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['jr', 'james', 'sr', 'william', 'manager', 'tim']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a for Loop to access  the elements of the bigger list.length(),and through indexing you can have the desired output.

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
```

use the append and range fuctionality to all the arguments,and construct an algorithm or even zip command.